# Splitting up a linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have an ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{dz}{dx} + a(y) + b(z) = 0$ 
Where $a$ is a function of $y$ and $b$ a function of $z$, then how do I solve this ODE for $y$ and $z$?

Can I split it in to two ODEs $\frac{dy}{dx} + a(y) = 0$ and $\frac{dz}{dx} + b(z) = 0$?

Then will the solution just be the sum of those solutions from the above two?

Comment: This seems fishy. I want to say no.

Comment: How would I go about solving it then?

Comment: Any pair of functions of the form $(\varphi(\cdot)+f(\cdot),\psi(\cdot)-f(\cdot))$, where $\varphi(\cdot)$ satisfies $dy/dx+a(y)=0$, $\psi(\cdot)$ satisfies $dz/dx+b(z)=0$, and $f(\cdot)$ is a differentiable function, satisfies the given **system** of ODEs. Incidentally, why do you call the system linear?

Comment: So what I did was correct?

Comment: Note that saying "if $\phi$ satisfies $dy/dx+ a(y)= 0$ and f satisfies $dy/dx+ b(y)= 0$ then $\phi+ f$ satisfies $d\phi/dx+ df/dy+ a(\phi)+ b(f)=0$" does not imply that all solutions of the last equation are of that form.

Comment: @theman No, I do not think so: A solution of a system of two ODEs is a **pair** of functions satisfying **both** equations in the system.  You have too few ODEs compared with the number of unknowns.

Comment: You should post the original system so we can help you if thats possible

Comment: @user247327  in the equation there is y and z which are differentiate wrt x

Comment: There isn't enough information to solve this system. You need a second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure will give only a subset of all solutions. You can choose $z$ arbitrarily, and then find $y$ by solving the equation
$$
y'+a(y)=-z'-b(z).
$$